# How could this code behave as I saw?

Tags: c++, puzzle, fencepost

I have a C++ application that had a one time assertion failure that I cannot reproduce.  Here is the code that failed once:

```
unsigned int test(std::vector<CAction> actionQueue) {
  unsigned int theLastCount = actionQueue.size() - 1;

  std::vector<CAction>::const_reverse_iterator rItr = actionQueue.rbegin();
  std::vector<CAction>::const_reverse_iterator rEndItr = actionQueue.rend();

  for (; rItr != rEndItr; ++rItr, --theLastCount) {
    const CAction &fileAction = *rItr;

    if (fileAction.test()) {
      continue;
    }
    return theLastCount;
  }

  assert(theLastCount == 0); // How could this fail?

  return theLastCount;
}
```

Somehow, theLastCount was not zero after the loop completed.

From my reading of the logic, this should be impossible unless:

1. Some other thread side effected the actionQueue (which I don't think is possible).
2. Some transient memory corruption occurred.

Am I missing something stupid here, is there a bug in my code shown?  Note that in the occurrence where I saw this, theLastCount should have been initialized to one as the vector had two elements.

Comment: How could it *NOT* fail?  See DeadMG's answer.

Comment: @PigBen If the inner return were hit.

Comment: But then the value is not tested.  You can't fail a test if you don't take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that if test() passed for all fileActions, theLastCount would be -1. Consider:

theLastCount starts at actionQueue.size() -1. You decrement it once for each item in actionQueue- that is, it is now actionQueue.size() - 1 - actionQueue.size() = -1. Think about it. theLastCount keeps the index of the current iterator. But when the current iterator is rend, then that is one iterator before the beginning of the array- which is -1.

Edit: Oh, it's unsigned. But since you only test for equality to zero, then the integral overflow doesn't matter an awful lot here.

Comment: Question I need to figure out now, is why isn't the reaching end of loop reproducible, something else has gone wrong elsewhere just once and it uncovered this bug which was a fencepost not hit previously despite thousands of prior invocations. A case of the old one bug uncovering another bug lurking a long time in the code.

Answer (score 2):

If your actionQueue is empty, then

```
unsigned int theLastCount = actionQueue.size() - 1;
```

will set `theLastCount` to the maximum possible unsigned integer.  The inner loop will never execute because the reverse iterators are equal to one another (`rbegin() == rend()` on empty containers), and so you'll hit the assertion with `theLastCount` equal to some staggeringly huge number.

Comment: Good point, true, however, in my case the function would have never been called in the first place if the vector were empty.

Comment: More generally, though, it seems like if the loop runs to completion you'll always have the max unsigned value.  You start the counter at `actionQueue.size() - 1` and then potentially decrement it `actionQueue.size()` times if you never hit the `return` statement in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
void test(std::vector<CAction> actionQueue) 
{
  unsigned int theLastCount = actionQueue.size() - 1;
  /** Omitted code ***/
  {
    /** Omitted code ***/
    return theLastCount;
  }
  return theLastCount;
}
```

Forget about the error that you're unable to reproduce. But here is one serious problem. The return type is `void`, yet you return `unsigned int`!! How come?

---

I think, you need to write this:

```
assert(theLastCount == -1);//correct assert!
```

That is because if the `test()` pass for all elements, then theLastCount should become -1. Since there is no element left, and theLastCount always is valid element index **if** there is element. Else it should become -1.

**NOTE :** Change the type of `theLastCount` from `unsigned int` to `int`.

Comment: Mistake creating written version of code for this post, actual code returns unsigned int.

Comment: @William: Okay. Then let me see what else is there!

Answer (score 1):

Please compile and run your code before you post it here! Firstly, this code doesn't compile (I'm not telling you why -- you can ask your compiler). Secondly, your assertion can never have succeeded, because theLastCount will always be (unsigned int)-1.

Comment: Code does compile, issue was the simplification of it for this posting.

Answer (score 0):

What if the queue is empty?

`theLastCount` will be -1, and then... :-)